# My modal form opens only on the first item

Tags: javascript, html

Here my HTML code and it is dynamic. So on my page when someone place comment it display and under comment section there is button called Reply, but when I am pressing that button it opens on the first comment, how can I make them open on each comment

```
<div class="comment-footer">
 <button onclick="openForm()">Reply</button>
   <form  id="comment" action="{% url 'add_reply_news' new.id comment.id %}" method="POST">
     {% csrf_token %}
      <div class="form-popup" id="myForm">
      <input type="text" name="text" rows="2" cols="100" id="message" placeholder="Enter text" required=""></textarea>
      <button type="button" class="btn cancel" onclick="closeForm()">Close</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Here is my js:

```
<script>
  function openForm() {
    document.getElementById("myForm").style.display = "block";
  }
  
  function closeForm() {
    document.getElementById("myForm").style.display = "none";
  }
  </script>
```

I made some script and it work perfect almost perfect, I do not know how to pass form to script, any Idea

```
<script>
    var varHtml = "<form method='post' ..... ><textarea name='reply' ></textarea> <input type='submit' /> </form>";

    var allElements = document.body.getElementsByClassName("replybtn");

    var addCommentField = function() {
      for (var i = 0; allElements.length > i; i++) {
        if (allElements[i] === this) {
          console.log("this " + i);

          if (document.getElementsByClassName("replyform")[i].innerHTML.length === 0) {
            document.getElementsByClassName("replyform")[i].innerHTML = varHtml;
          }

        }
      }
    };


    for (var i = 0; i < allElements.length; i++) {
      allElements[i].addEventListener('click', addCommentField, false);
    }
  </script>
```

So basically I want to change that

```
var varHtml = "<form method='post' ..... ><textarea name='reply'
></textarea> <input type='submit' /> </form>";
```

to something like that `var varHtml = "<form id='comment' action='{% url 'add_reply_news' new.id comment.id %}' method='POST' >{% csrf_token %}<input type='text' name='text' rows='2' cols='100' id='message' placeholder='Enter reply' required=''></textarea> <input type='submit' /> </form>";`, but it did not work, give some error since it is Python i guess.

So I want to know is there any way to actually pass from HTML the form to var variables in JS.
Something like var varHtml = form from some div class or form with some Id from html page

Comment: IDs are supposed to be unique. `document.getElementById("myForm")` always returns the first element with that ID, no matter which button you click on.

Comment: so should I use document.getElementsByClassname?

Comment: Yes. Then you can restrict it to the same DIV as the button they clicked on.

Comment: You need to pass `this` or `event` to `openForm()` so it will know which button was clicked.